# Sick TiM300 Laserscanner Driver

Tags: ros, driver, laserscanner, sick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,

is there a Sick TiM300 Laserscanner Driver for ROS available? It is a relatively new and tiny Laserscanner connected via USB. So far, I only found http://www.ros.org/wiki/sicktoolbox, but I think this one is for the big older ones with ethernet connection.

A friend of mine got a driver, but only for Player/Stage (which seems to be inactive since 2 years). If there is no solution for ROS yet, I would try to convert this driver to use it in ROS. But as I have no experience in ROS so far, I would be very happy if someone could give me a hint where to find a driver or at least give me some useful information on how to integrate the old player/stage driver into the sicktoolbox, e.g.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35366/sick-tim300-laserscanner-driver/) by [Adrian Haarbach](https://answers.ros.org/users/2508/adrian-haarbach/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-05-31

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, the guys from the University of Osnabrück recently published a TIM3XX driver. It is available here: http://kos.informatik.uni-osnabrueck.de/sick_tim3xx.git
I just tested it today and it works out of the box. Unlike the hokuyo scanners it does not use a symmetric min/max angle however and the "middle" of the scan thus coincides with the y axis of the scanner coordinate frame.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The UOS guys have just provided one. It should be in this [rosinstall](http://kos.informatik.uos.de/uos-ros-pkg.rosinstall).

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-05-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just for future reference (I just stumbled over this question), the wiki page for our driver is here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/sick_tim3xx.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-07-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1